# meaning of the sentence towards time obligation?

Tags: meaning

> When a player discards a card, you may choose to take that card from the discarded pile of cards.

Must I take the card immediately after the player discards it or can I wait until it is my turn to play?

Comment: It is not clear from these instructions when precisely you can take the card. Note: Your question was very unclear so I have edited it. Please tell me if it still means what you intended.

Comment: yes, good editing. thank you. 
the presence of When at the beginning is not related to the timing of the action but it is a simple statement describing the first action ? is that true ?

Comment: I'm perplexed by the title of this question as relates to the content... what are you trying to say in the title?  As for the meaning, given my own personal history in gaming, I would assume that "when a player discards a card" means exactly that... it happens at the time of discard.

Comment: yes, i wanted to know the meaning of the sentence related to the obligation of time

Comment: yes, but note that this game is a turn oriented game. this means that the holder of the card gets to interfere in other players' turns.

Comment: The instructions are bad in general. For example: No doubt it is the cards in the pile that have been discarded; the pile is not discarded. So *pile of discarded cards*, not *discarded pile of cards*.

Answer (score 2):

> When a player discards a card, you may choose to take that card from the discarded pile of cards.

Having read the comment by Holly K, this now makes more sense to me. I agree—it means you must take it immediately. If it was meant to be more flexible then the instruction could have been:

> When a player has discarded a card, you may choose to take that card from the discarded pile of cards.

Comment: There are very few card games I know of that result in a free-for-all-see-who-can-grab-it-first when a card is discarded.  They usually  offer the choice of  "when it's your turn you may choose to draw a card from the deck or pickup off the discard pile."

Comment: I think the problem is that I'm trying to understand the grammar whereas others are interpreting the sentence based on a knowledge of card-playing. If someone comes up with a better answer I'll delete mine.

Comment: I'm trying to make sense out of the statement grammar wise cause as a game card my interpretation of it; is that when the first action ( another player discards a certain card ) happens on the other players' turn, you ( the holder of the card ) may take this card from the discarded cards ( second action ) which happens on your turn normally.

Comment: @SeifMounir- Typically card games are turn-based.  Therefore a player can only *do* something with their cards **when it is their turn**.  So when it's my turn I can draw cards, "play" cards and discard cards.  Other players must wait for it to become their turn before they can draw, play, and discard.  Given that premise, when a player discards a card to the discard pile it is *their* turn.  The "holder" of that card is the player whose turn it is until it lands on the discard pile at which point no one is the holder of the card.  It doesn't make sense for him to then pick up that same card.

Answer (score 0):

Grammar and idiom can only take you so far.  Adverbial clauses starting with *when* can describe a general condition, with the meaning of "any time":

> **When** you pass a spark through a mixture of hydrogen and oxygen gases,
>   an interesting thing will happen before you get wet.

But the *when* may also mean a particular moment:

> The carpenter said to his assistant holding the hammer, "**When** I nod my
>   head, you hit it."

We don't know whether anything interesting happened after the last sentence, but whatever happened is tied to a particular time, the moment of head-nodding.

To find out which usage applies to the card game, you'll have to consult the remainder of the rules to find out which actions, if any, may take place out of turn.